# Manually break an equation chain and adjust indentation

Tags: math-mode, equations, split

If an equation chain is too long I normally spit the chain in the following way

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        x&=y\\&=z\\&=w
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

However, if `x` takes too much horizontal space, I would like to introduce a break immediately after `x`, insert 12 blanks and then insert `y`. The other breaks (afer `y` and after `z`) should still be there and each new line should be indented by 12 blanks. How can I do this?

Comment: I think what you want is `align`. Look for it.

Comment: Please provide more realistic MWE, which will show what you like to achieve. Some sketch of desired result also be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your are looking for `\MoveEqLeft` from the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \MoveEqLeft \rule{5cm}{1.5ex} \\
        &= \rule{6cm}{1.5ex} \\
        &= \rule{4cm}{1.5ex} \\
        &= \rule{2cm}{1.5ex}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]